# How to make an attachment file sent via "POST - Send chat message" from Graph API displayable in Teams channel?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, power-automate

With a Flow from Power Automate, I am sending a POST Request to send a chat message with a file attachment in a Team's channel in MS Teams as documented in the Graph API [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-send-a-message-with-file-attachment-in-it)

It works well and I am able to get the message with a reference to the file in the channel as shown in the following picture :

[Working sent message with attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfHFZ.png)

The file is actually an attachment to a sharepoint item in a List that I am retrieving in the flow and sending back in the message with the correct ETag and absolute path as contentUrl:

**The problem is the following:** when I click on the file in the message, it does not display and an error message saying that the file might not exist anymore or that I do not have the right to access it appears (see next picture). Still, when I try to open the file in the browser (by right-clicking the file) it does open the url in the browser and download the file.

[Error message in Teams after clicking on the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blYrO.png)

**What I would like**: I would like that when I click on the file, it displays itself in Teams

**What I've already tried**:

1. Sending the contentBytes as base64 of the attachment file with the contentType as MIME type of the file. --> Unfortunately, the request body is then not accepted. I think that the JSON schema is not respected because of contentBytes
2. Checking if the file has the necessary rights and permission to be accessed
3. Trying to use parameters at then end of the url like '?web=1'

None of the above allowed me to solve the problem. The nearest forum/discussion that I found about this problem is the following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/335233/sorry-this-file-has-been-deleted-or-moved-teams-gr.html. Unfortunately the solution proposed (changing the attachment id with the sourcedoc id) did not work for me as I was unable to get the "sourcedoc" or "source ID" mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried doing same with Graph explorer?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that is working for this problem is to first copy the attachment in a sharepoint library and then use this copy as the attachment.

Comment: Coould you provide more detail on the solution? I am having the same issue. What is required to do?